# Sencha Touch 2.3 - theming - @include function - Compass

Tags: extjs, sass, sencha-touch, compass-sass

I am trying to change theme in my project with the following code in the app.scss file

It seems that if I just have the first set of two @imports, the `$base-color: green` does not take effect. If I have just the second set of @imports, it looks fine.

If I have both the set of @imports, there appears to be a hybrid theme in some way between cupertino and the default, but in green. I don't understand why the second one won't supercede the first one

```
$base-color: green;


@import 'sencha-touch/cupertino-classic';
@import 'sencha-touch/cupertino-classic/all';

@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';



// Custom code goes here..
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to overwrite SCSS variables when compiling to CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089717/how-to-overwrite-scss-variables-when-compiling-to-css)