# Ionic sass button styling

Tags: sass, ionic-framework

Say for instance I want to change the color of the `$positive` button in ionic from the blue to a green. So i run

```
> ionic sass
```

This sets up the sass implementation for the project. Then in the `ionic.app.sass` file I start overwriting. So now my brand colors are green so I change the sass variable `$positive` to a green. However this does not change the active states on the button. In the `_variables.sass` the code is

```
$button-positive-active-bg:       darken($positive, 10%) !default;
$button-positive-active-border:   darken($positive, 10%) !default;
```

But is still seems to be pulling from the old blue color. I am new to .sass having worked more in .less ( which is honestly so much better ;).

Not too sure what is going on here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089717/how-to-overwrite-scss-variables-when-compiling-to-css

Comment: Similar but no . I do have @import of ionic after the declaration of the variables in the ionic.app.scss file