# Scss: Override Variables

Tags: css, variables, sass

Is there a way to override variables in SCSS without mixins or functions?
My setup looks like this:

Input:

```
$color: red !default;

selector {
  color: $color;
}

$color: blue;
```

Output:

```
selector {
  color: red;
}
```

I already tried to use `!global` but this does not work either.
I am not sure, if this is even possible in SCSS without using mixins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite SCSS variables when compiling to CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089717/how-to-overwrite-scss-variables-when-compiling-to-css)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the variable before it gets declared with `!default`.
To achieve the result you want your code needs to look like this:

```
$color: blue;

$color: red !default;

selector {
   color: $color;
}
```

[Here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_default) is some info about how `!default` works.