# Sass - Setting the font family with material web components

Tags: web, sass, material-components, material-components-web

I am using material web components in my project and I would like to change the font family. I was going through their [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-typography) and I have tried to do that by setting the variable in my sass file like this:

```
$mdc-typography-font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif !default;
```

But, that didn't work, in the documentation it also says that sass mixin sets the font:

```
mdc-typography-base
```

How can I change the mixin to use a different font-family?

Comment: Have you added `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">` to `<head>`?

Comment: Yes, I did, I have that in the head

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out by removing `!default` flag:

```
$mdc-typography-font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
```

Also, don't forget to embed Google Fonts in the head tag:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Nothing has changed for me in the project, everything still has Roboto font

Comment: What's your setup? How you're importing components?

Comment: In my app.sass I am importing material web components like this ```@import 'material-components-web/material-components-web';``` and then below it I am importing the ```variables``` file where I have set the variable.

Comment: You should import variables first, and only then Material Components.

Comment: How would that work, wouldn't then variable from material components override my variable?

Comment: You were right, I thought I would then override my variable with the material components if I would import material components after the variables file?

Comment: Sass works another way - it will take first variable declaration. Here're Sass variables explained on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17090334/9180111