# How to import a sass theming module from node_modules folder

Tags: npm, vue.js, sass

I created a small vue.js library that is using scss for styling and published that as npm package. It works well with a default theme included into the package. But what if I would like to provide a custom theme from the application that consumes that npm package, how would you do that?

The source for a very basic version of the library is here: https://github.com/gwildu/gwi-vue-components

The idea is, that you would copy paste the styling folder somewhere (e.g., into your application directory or into another npm package) and configure the library package to import from that copyied directory.

Answer (score 1):

I did some investigation myself and found that there is a big discussion about having dynamic imports in sass since years. This [issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/739) (open since 2013) claims to add such a feature (they call it `load`). Not sure, how actively sass is still developed and when this feature will be supported. For now I see 3 possible solutions:

1. move to LESS as it supports dynamic imports. [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com) gives you a hint about how [theming](https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html) could be done in LESS
2. It is possible to import from relative paths in SASS. That way you are also able to import from a parent directory of your package root directory (your application directory) like, e.g., `@import '../../theme/index';`. You would support somewhere in your package an example of a theme that the consumer then would have to copy to, e.g., the root directory of his application and adjust it to his needs. In your package you would then import the theme from that directory in the consumers application folder. The downside is, that the package would not work out of the box
3. You have a default theme in your package and you add some instructions into the readme how the user can override that theme in a build script. The consumer would have to copy the default theme to his application directory, adjust it to his needs and in the build script he would replace the theme in, e.g., `node_modules/your-library-package-folder/theme/` by the theme in your application folder.

To be complete here is the approach with a dynamic import (that is not yet supported by SASS):

4. In your main theme file in the library package (that would be imported by the components) you would do a relative import of kind of a config file from the consumers application folder like in approach 2 (see above) but that config file yould not contain the theme but only the import path of the theme in a variable. that variable then would be used by the package main theme file to import the theme. For making the library work out of the box, I guess there would be a way to have a default theme as backup if the config file in the consumers directory would not exist (not tested)

Update:
I tried approach 3 but failed to get something useful. The issue with that approach is that you would have to somehow sync your custome theme with the default theme when you update the library to a higher version which might get too complex to handle in a reasonable way. Then I tried to use the overwrite feature of SASS as described here: [How to overwrite SCSS variables when compiling to CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089717/how-to-overwrite-scss-variables-when-compiling-to-css) which led me to approach

5. In your library component you first import a file with possible custom variables and you declare your variables in the library as default.

The issue with that approach is that SASS does not support optional imports. The file with the custom variables have to exist somewhere. So if the library updates you again have to sync your custom theme files for each component / file that was changed in the library. Apparently SASS also don't want to support such a feature in the future: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/779 which is sad, as it seems to me an essential feature for being able to do theming without a highly complex build step.

Overall, it seems SASS itself is making every effort to prevent a simple theming approach which makes me think of moving back to LESS again. Not having a simple way for static theming in SASS in my opinion outweight the cons of not having an easy way to define custom functions in LESS.

Comment: It seems there is a way to do theming with SASS, https://vuematerial.io/themes/concepts, it looks a bit complicated from the implementation side (https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material), but I like the api for the developer that uses the library. It might take some time to dig into it, if someone has experience with this attempt, a comment or answer would be appreciated...