# Overwrite CSS variable through angular template

Tags: angular, css

I am using an internal library where all the widths are set using a CSS variable `$drawer-width` Here is a snip of the file:

```
$drawer-width: 380px;
$zindex: 1015;
.right-drawer-slide-in {
    margin-right: $drawer-width;
    animation: content-slide-in 0.5s 1;
}

.right-drawer-open {
    margin-right: $drawer-width;
    z-index: $zindex + 1;
}
```

In normal cases, to customize a class, we either can define local css class which  overwrite that custom attribute. But in this case, how I can overwrite css variable drawer-width?

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: check this answer on how to override SCSS variables https://stackoverflow.com/a/17090334/606104 . it could be possible this way.

Comment: yes right... thanks