# Why I can't overwrite scss variables?

Tags: variables, sass, css-modules

For example, I have this kind of code

In scss file at the top I have something like this:

```
$bgc-color: var(--color-daybreak-blue-6);
```

Then I use this in class, and it works perfectly.

```
.primary {
  background-color: $bgc-color;
  color: $bgc-color;
}
```

Now I want to change `$bgc-color` value based on `media queries`

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    $bgc-color: var(--color-red-1);
  }
```

And this is not working, I have still main value  `$bgc-color: var(--color-daybreak-blue-6);`

In my project I used `React` and `Sass`, but what may be important I use also `scss.modules`, so my file is `button.module.scss`

Does anyone know what I do wrong? in normal css files, when I use css variables is working perfectly :(

Comment: You can follow that [stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089717/how-to-overwrite-scss-variables-when-compiling-to-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite SCSS variables when compiling to CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089717/how-to-overwrite-scss-variables-when-compiling-to-css)